# Decimales al editar registro con modal

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenos dias al hacer la edición de un registro que es el total de la factura me nuestra el precio así;   1,500.00€ que es tal como quiero, pero al editar el registro como me sale 1,500.00, si no lo edito se me convierte en 1.00€ y si lo edito pero dejando el "." tambien me pasa lo mismo, oslo funciona si borro el campo y pongo de nuevo 15000. Este campo en la SQL lo tengo como `decimal(10,2)`y luego en la query para que se vea bien hago así:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT((pedidos.Fecha),'%d/%m/%Y') Fecha, 
    pedidos.id AS pedID, DATE_FORMAT((pedidos.Vencimiento),'%d/%m/%Y') 
    Vencimiento, pedidos.Producto AS idPr, pedidos.Tipo, 
  FORMAT(pedidos.Total, 2) Total, pedidos.Estado, productos.id, 
    productos.producto, productos.alias, Usuarios.IdUsuario AS idUs, 
    Usuarios.Nombre 
  FROM pedidos, productos, Usuarios WHERE 
    pedidos.Producto = productos.id AND pedidos.Iduser = 
    Usuarios.IdUsuario");
```

Si os dais cuenta la fomateo con esto `FORMAT(pedidos.Total, 2) Total,`

En la edición de registro esta así:

```
<?php
 $id = $_POST['eIdp'];
 $cliente = $_POST['eIDCliente'];
 $producto = $_POST['select2-2'];
 $eFecha = $_POST['eFecha'];
 $eVencimiento = $_POST['eVencimiento'];
 $estado = $_POST['select2-1'];
 $tipo = $_POST['select2-4'];
 $total = $_POST['eTotal'];

 $resultes = "Update pedidos Set Fecha='$eFecha', 
              Vencimiento='$eVencimiento', Estado='$estado', 
              Producto='$producto', Tipo='$tipo', Total='$total' 
              where id= $id";


 if ( !mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $resultes)) {
      die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
 }

 mysqli_close($mysqli);
 ?>
```

Comment: Yo quitaría el formateo de la sql y lo dejaría para la parte cliente aunque lo realmente importante es que en el modal añadas un controlador para cuando el campo que contiene el valor recibe el foco que le quite el formato y otro controlador para cuando pierda el foco y le dé formato de nuevo

Comment: Hola @JaviMollá eso me gustaria aprender a hacerlo por que de hecho en los formularios hice algo parecido pero no logre justo lo que me dices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que el campo de la base de datos es un dato numérico y debes tratarlo como tal, no le debes enviar ni comas ni símbolos de moneda.

```
. . .
$tipo = $_POST['select2-4'];
$total_wf = $_POST['eTotal'];
$total = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/s', '', $total_wf); // Se elimina la coma y algun otro caracter.

$resultes = "Update pedidos Set ..." // El query
. . .
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! solucionado, gracias @aeportugal